# css3 animation on click

Tags: javascript, animation, css, onclick

The following zip contains the website html and required files: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/4281191/login.zip

When you hover the html (html:hover) you see a animation that transforms the container into a loginbox, I want that to happen when I click on "Login" at the "Hello, Guest" menu instead.

Anyway to get this done? I'm new to js...

Additional info:

the css is inside the html,
and the css3 animation gets triggered by:

```
html:hover id/class {
    property: value;
}
```

Thanks for any help!
And I can't vote at comments since I don't have enough reputation...but I could do some free design work for the person who helps me ^^

Comment: i think your chances are bad when people need to download the files. try to put it online somewhere and post a link, or even better, edit your post and add the relevant code here.

Comment: post your code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). I have no reason to trust that your zip is not going to give me a virus.

Comment: I risked it and there's no virus...

Comment: Are people so scared of virusses that they don't even trust dropbox links >.>...

And a online link can have virusses too so that doesn't change a thing. And this isn't 5 lines of code so it would be way too huge and slow on jsfiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know much about animations, but for what matters here, you could use something like the .classname:active or .classname:focus selectors. But as soon as you click something inside it (e.g. a text box), the style will disappear.

So, for this, it really depends. Do you just want a menu that has links that take the user to another page (for this case, you'll be fine) or do you want a login form (for this case, forget it, use jquery)?

For today and future reference, save this link because it'll be your best friend:

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

### Update

Yes, I hovered but I didn't look at the code. I looked now and, unfortunately, the answer is no. You can't affect some upper level object like that using CSS.

For that use jQuery. The simpler way would be use jQuery to add a class to the element you want to change (like $("#the-object-id").addClass('class-name')). To keep the effect add the duration argument. Read this page about [Adding a class using jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/demos/addClass).

Comment: You tried the html in the zip and hovered it? And looked at least at the code? I could use selectors but the element triggering the loginbox animation is a child of the elements of the animation and child elements can't effect a parent element...

Comment: The jquery code did the job :D
I just had to use !important; at some places ^^